# Netbeans showing $_POST, var_dump not

Tags: php, netbeans, yii2

I have a strange problem. I send some data by post, and my application semms no to see this data, whilst NetBeans in debugging mode sees them all correctly. What can cause such a situation?

[image]

[image]

I'm using Yii2 framework. I have a Model named 'PaymentChosenBank' that has FK to 'PaymentOption' and 'PaymentBank'. The form I'm trying to upload is connected with 'PaymentOption' only, so I created public variable $chosen_bank_id in 'PaymentOption' model, to be able to create 'PaymentChosenBank' later with this ID that I got. Let me know if I explain myself clearly.

Comment: Could you show us where in your code this is happening?

Comment: @Jerodev I'm using Yii2 framework. I have a Model named 'PaymentChosenBank' that has FK to 'PaymentOption' and 'PaymentBank'. The form I'm trying to upload is connected with 'PaymentOption' only, so I created public variable $chosen_bank_id in 'PaymentOption' model, to be able to create 'PaymentChosenBank' later with this ID that I got. Let me know if I explain myself clearly.

Comment: Have you added a rule in your model for `chosen_bank_id`?

Comment: @topher You're my hero of today, man! Thanks, as always, I forgot to add the rule.